# What もう means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> もう少し大きな声で話してください (Please speak slightly louder.)

What もう means/stands for in this sentence?

Comment: Try looking up もう少し rather than just もう.

Comment: The third definition [here](https://www.weblio.jp/content/もう?dictCode=SGKDJ): ３ 現にある事物・状態などに、同じものを付け加える気持ちを表す語。さらに。いま。「もうちょっとで車にひかれるところだった」「もう片方の靴下が見つからない」

Answer (score 1):

This もう is an adverb that means something along the lines of "more" or "additionally". In your case, you can think this もう corresponds to '-er':

- 少し大きな声で
  in a bit loud voice
- **もう**少し大きな声で
  in a bit loud**er** voice

The latter can be used even when the listener is already trying to speak in a loud voice. You can remember もう少し and もうちょっと as set expressions that mean "a little **more** ～".

Another example:

- 5分待つ
  to wait for five minutes
- **もう**5分待つ
  to wait for **another** five minutes